# celeryd dead but subsys locked

Tags: python, django, linux, centos, celery

I get the message 'celeryd dead but subsys locked' when I check if celery is running.

I get a [failed] message when trying to stop the service, and as soon as I start it I get this message again.

I have deleted the var/lock/subsys/celeryd file which doesn't help at all.

I noticed that the PID and log files are not being created in the specified place either, but the service is starting with an [ok] message.

I am running CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem.

This is what I did to solve it. After deleting the `/var/lock/subsys/celeryd` file, I tried restarting the process. It said OK, but the process did not restart (i.e. the pid of the process did not change). Then I killed that process using

```
sudo kill -9 $(pidof celeryd)
```

Then it started working fine again.